# How can I match two table indexes using fuzzy string metrics, while preventing duplicate matches in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools, fuzzy-search

I'm trying to combine two tables together in python, but the row titles/keys are sometimes different, so I'm using [jellyfish](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jellyfish/) to compare the keys and generating a list of percentages for each possible match (seen in match_list below)

My issue is around finding the best combination of matches based on these percentages, without having any repeated keys.

For example, lets imagine table_1 and table_2 had the matches presented in match_list below. The maximum match for each row WITHOUT considering if the other rows have the *same match* can be found using the code at the bottom.

```
table_1 = [['t1_key_1', ['t1_value_1']],
           ['t1_key_2', ['t1_value_2']],
           ['t1_key_n', ['t1_value_n']]]


table_2 = [['t2_key_1', 't2_value_1'],
           ['t2_key_2', 't2_value_2'],
           ['t2_key_n', 't2_value_n']] 

match_list = [['t1_key_1',
                    [['t2_key_1', 0.9],
                     ['t2_key_2', 0.9],
                     ['t2_key_n', 0.6]]],
              ['t1_key_2',
                   [['t2_key_1', 0.9],
                    ['t2_key_2', 0.8],
                    ['t2_key_n', 0.2]]],
              ['t1_key_n',
                   [['t2_key_1', 0.7],
                    ['t2_key_2', 0.9],
                    ['t2_key_n', 0.8]]]
            ]


result = []
for row in match_list:
    row[1].sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    result.append([row[0],row[1][0]])

print(result)
```

returns

```
[['t1_key_1', ['t2_key_1', 0.9]],
 ['t1_key_2', ['t2_key_1', 0.9]], 
 ['t1_key_n', ['t2_key_2', 0.9]]]
```

Note: that 't2_key_1' is repeated for both 't1_key_1' and 't1_key_2', this is the repetition issue

So my question is, how can I make it so the set of matches only uses unique values, while maximising the match percentage?

Desired output:

```
[['t1_key_1', ['t2_key_2', 0.9]],
 ['t1_key_2', ['t2_key_1', 0.9]], 
 ['t1_key_n', ['t2_key_n', 0.8]]]
```

I think it might be possible to calculate the total match value for each possible combination (where all t2_keys are unique), and then select the highest, but I couldn't work out how to make a list of all possible unique combinations.

*Also, this is the first questions I've asked on here, so feel free to go hard with suggestions on ways to improve my question explanation etc - and apologies in advance for the terrible title, it was a struggle to word!*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Also, this is the first questions I've asked on here, so feel free to go hard with suggestions on ways to improve my question explanation etc - and apologies in advance for the terrible title, it was a struggle to word!" The reason you are struggling with asking the question is not because of difficulty with English. The reason is because you have not put in the [necessary](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) effort to analyze the problem, break it down into steps and figure out *where exactly you are stuck*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`itertools.product` can produce all the combinations.

```
import itertools

table_1 = [['t1_key_1', ['t1_value_1']],
           ['t1_key_2', ['t1_value_2']],
           ['t1_key_n', ['t1_value_n']]]


table_2 = [['t2_key_1', 't2_value_1'],
           ['t2_key_2', 't2_value_2'],
           ['t2_key_n', 't2_value_n']] 

match_list = [['t1_key_1',
                    [['t2_key_1', 0.9],
                     ['t2_key_2', 0.9],
                     ['t2_key_n', 0.6]]],
              ['t1_key_2',
                   [['t2_key_1', 0.9],
                    ['t2_key_2', 0.8],
                    ['t2_key_n', 0.2]]],
              ['t1_key_n',
                   [['t2_key_1', 0.7],
                    ['t2_key_2', 0.9],
                    ['t2_key_n', 0.8]]]
            ]

maxscore = 0
maxcombo = []
for a,b,c in itertools.product( *(ml[1] for ml in match_list) ):
    if a[0] == b[0] or b[0] == c[0] or a[0] == c[0]:
        continue
    score = a[1]+b[1]+c[1]
    if score > maxscore:
        maxscore = score
        maxcombo = (a,b,c)
print(maxscore)
print([[k1[0],m1] for k1,m1 in zip(match_list, maxcombo)])
```

Output:

```
2.6
[['t1_key_1', ['t2_key_2', 0.9]], ['t1_key_2', ['t2_key_1', 0.9]], ['t1_key_n', ['t2_key_n', 0.8]]]
```